# Background from a parent div moves when I give the child div a margin

Tags: html, css, margin

I've been making a site for the last few hours but I'm stuck on the last bit of the job. When I give my child div a margin my parent div moves his background for some reason.

```
<div class='actors'>
<div class='actorsbox'> 
    <div class='actorsboxtext'>hello world</div>    
</div>
```

```
.actors {
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url("../rock5.jpg");
background-size:contain;}

.actorsbox {
border: 3px solid black;
background-color: white;
height: 420px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
margin-top: 40px;
border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;}

.actorsboxtext {
height: 380px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;}
```

I don't think the problem is in the code above so here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8p3hvytp/1/
The div I'm talking about is at the bottom of the page. I colored a border red and the background red so you can see the space that's created when I give my child div a margin.

I hope someone could help me with this because I need it done by today! So it's sort of a big problem for me so thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to add that the same code is in my other divs too (at the top of the page) but they don't have that problem for some reason.

I really have no clue what's wrong.

Comment: hey i update fiddle for you. you only need to add transparent border to actor class, checkout this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/arpan2010/uLh4t3oq/

Comment: Thanks a lot man :)! I already resolved the problem by adding a float to the actor class. Someone else here gave that tip, but I really apreciate that you've taken the time to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give a float to .actors.

```
.actors{
   float: left;
   height: 500px;
   width: 100%;
   background-image: url("../rock5.jpg");
   background-size:contain;
}
```

or

```
.actors{
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 500px;
   width: 100%;
   background-image: url("../rock5.jpg");
   background-size:contain;
}
```

Comment: is it fixed...?

Comment: If I could then I would kiss you right now :P! or give you a hug, either way thanks a lot man! It was the float that I didn't think of. I'm going to check out the property of that today because it's a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It is **expected** behaviour that the parent's background would move when giving a child a margin, as a background **includes** margins:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

You're probably looking for **padding** instead:

```
.actorsbox {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

I recommend you check out the [**box-model**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) for information on how margins and paddings are calculated :)

Comment: No sorry that's not it (I tried it), maybe I asked my question wrong so I updated the backgrounds to be colors in my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8p3hvytp/1/

The div that I'm talking about is at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Oke problem resolved, it was the float that I forgot to add in the div. I'm still not clear why I needed the float for the background image but that's some more food for thought today.

Thanks all of you guys, I really apreciate your help :)! (You saved my ass)